# How to fix font sizing difference between chrome and firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, font-size

I am trying to solve a font sizing difference between chrome and firefox latest versions on os x lion.

Try this page in both Chrome and Firefox: http://ccs.btcny.net/redhook/

The colored tag on the top of each box diminishes properly until I reach row 4 where it holds it's size instead of reducing. Chrome displays properly. Firefox does not.

I'm using ems for font size and reducing the size of my font as the boxes get smaller...by setting each new row's.

Comment: I tried forcing the text sizes on each subsequent row's .term-tag and the browser ignores that style.

Answer (score 0):

The difference could potentially be fixed by running separate CSS depending on the browser, by doing some user agent sniffing with PHP (or the dynamic language of your choice). Simply put a line of PHP code which states that:

```
<?php
if (Firefox (not the actual UA sniffing code here)) {
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../yourfirefoxstyle.css\">;
}

if {WebKit (Chrome or Safari, again, not actual code here)) {
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../yourwebkitstyle.css\">;
}
else {
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../styleforotherbrowsers.css\">;
}
?>
```